# Filter Windows Event Security logs by Source IP Address

Tags: security, windows-event-log

I can't seem to get the Event Viewer to filter on the source IP address that is in the Security Event Log in Windows server Event Viewer.  This is the XML query string I'm using.  Where did I go wrong?

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name="SourceNetworkAddress"]="1.2.3.4"]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: Logparser might also help, I find it easier than the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax...

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[EventData[Data[@Name="IpAddress"] and (Data="1.2.3.4")]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Comment: This answer needs a lot of improvement. For a start you could explain what the difference is and why it matters.

Comment: What would be great is a link to a comprehensive list of property names available, and a description of the syntax.  I was able to figure this out from trial and error and thought I'd share what finally worked.

Comment: The property names are available in the event viewer, and they are unique for each event id. If you display an event in XML then you should be able to see them.